# Identify a Marvel character with a two-piece magenta mask that does not cover the mouth

Tags: marvel, character-identification

I purchased this item for my son, I'm not a Marvel expert and can identify all the characters except the last one that is used for the letter 'L':

[image: Image of pyjama set decorated with Marvel comics characters]

I can identify Captain America, Iron Man, Hulk, Thor, and Spider-Man, but who is the last one?

Weirdly, this character doesn't appear on the pyjama bottoms.

There is [a higher resolution copy of the image](https://johnlewis.scene7.com/is/image/JohnLewis/002291062?$rsp-pdp-port-1440$) on [the original website](http://www.johnlewis.com/john-lewis-boys'-marvel-classic-pyjama-set-navy/p2487087#media-overlay_show).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It's the superhero archer [Hawkeye](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawkeye_%28comics%29).

I found this image that may have been used for the shirt.

[image: Hawkeye]

Comment: missed it by *that* much

Comment: @NKCampbell Much like Hawkeye, I have a very quick draw.

Comment: well played sir :)

Comment: this is what I thought but he didn't appear on the pyjama bottoms so I wasn't sure plus I don't have ready access to some vintage Marvel comics, many thanks this will appease my son's curiosity. He thought it was Ant-Man for some reason